# Blinking led using interrupts in AVR

Tags: avr, interrupts

I want to learn how to work with interrupts and I have done my first try.

I have done a very simple circuit based on ATtiny13.

There's a led in PB1 and a button in PB3. When the button is pressed, PB3 pin change its state from low level to high level, this produces an external interrupt. The code of this interrupt, makes the led turn on for 500ms.

[schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyhpz.png)

This is my code, what's wrong here? I'm getting this warning:

> 'PCINT3_vect' appears to be a misspelled signal handler, missing
>   __vector prefix [-Wmisspelled-isr]

What's wrong here?

```
#define F_CPU 9600000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

ISR(PCINT3_vect)
{
        PORTB |= (1<<PB1);
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1);
        _delay_ms(500);
}

void SystemInit(void)
{
        PCMSK |= (1<<PCINT3);   // pin change mask: listen to portb, pin PB3
        GIMSK |= (1<<PCIE); // enable PCINT interrupt
        sei();          // enable all interrupts

}

int main(void)
{       
    DDRB |= (1<<PB1);
    DDRB |= (1<<PB3);
    SystemInit();

    while (1) 
    {       
    }
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: I think ATTiny13 supports interrupts only on PC0.

Comment: @VladimirCravero AVR pin change interrupts have one vector per port and there is a mask register to enable individual pins. If multiple pins are used, the port must be checked to see which pin changed.

Comment: Never ever call blocking delays in ISR, an ISR should be executed as fast as possible.

Comment: so, where should I place the delays?

Comment: Set a flag in the ISR, check the flag in main, if set blink the LED with delays and clear the flag as well. Currently it is not an issue for you but it is a bad habit so you should not get used to it.

Comment: my first try would have been us the internal timer interrupt on roll over the interrupt toggles the state of the led...with a push button you have to do more work and we have not even gotten into the switch bouncing, causing potentially multiple interrupts which may or may not be a problem based on the chip and software.

Comment: you could have the led change state for each button press, then add a delay in a future version of the program (in the foreground dont put delays in the interrupt).

Comment: instead of the foreground and a flag you can also have the button press cause one handler to set the led and start a timer, the timer times out, interrupts, that handler turns off the led, and not have any flags nor foreground code related to the led or the delay.

Answer (score 3):

This is the ATTiny13's interrupt vector table.

[image]

PCINT3 is not an interrupt vector. You need to change that to PCINT0. It looks like you have the PCI and mask set properly. You should be able to make that change and have your interrupts work. You also need to add initialization to make your push button work.

```
DDRB |= (0<<PB3); //Pushbutton input
PORTB |= (1<<PB3); //Enable Pushbutton pull-up
DDRB |= (1<<PB1); //LED output
```

That will enable the internal pull-up and allow an edge to happen on a button press. This will likely work for simulation, but a real circuit will need some debounce either in hardware or software.

Comment: so, what I have to change is ISR(PCINT3_vect) into ISR(PCINT0_vect), right?

Comment: @Salva That should do it.

Comment: it seems not to work: http://i65.tinypic.com/33y2kyb.png

Comment: @Salva See my edit.

Comment: right now, it enters in the interrupt when it PB3 goes from low to high level, and from high to low as well. How do you do just to set the interrupt to be called when PB3 goes from low to high ?

Comment: Check the datasheet, can't remember if the option to interrupt only on rising or falling edges is there or not. Worst case, use an if statement to check the pin state before executing the blink code.

Comment: I changed the circuit into: http://i63.tinypic.com/25z741u.jpg but what you said does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

According to the table [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html), there is no `PCINT3` interrupt on ATtiny13:
[image]

Comment: so, I can't place an interrupt in PB3, right? I though I could

Comment: You can, but you can only enable one interrupt per port. So you could have one interrupt in PORTB, one in PORTD, one in PORTD etc., but you cannot have multiple interrupts in a single port.